# Mac script for deleting a file if another file with same name and different extension is not present in the folder

Tags: macos, shell, applescript

I have few files in the folder. for eg.

```
1.jpg,
1.nef,
2.nef,
3.jpg,
3.nef
```

Using a script, I want to delete the .nef files if a .jpg file with same name is not present ( in above list, 2.nef).
I have thousands of files in the folder. I am unable to develop this logic in shell script. Can this be done using AppleScript.

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 3):

You could also run a command like this in Terminal:

```
cd /path/to/directory; for f in *.nef; do [[ -e ${f%nef}jpg ]] || echo rm "$f"; done
```

Remove `echo` to actually delete the files.

Comment: Sorry, this did work and it was very fast. I couldn't time it but it was about as fast (maybe faster) than my applescript.

Comment: if i wanted to delete nef file only if the jpg existed how would i modify this

Comment: @mcgrailm Replace `||` with `&&`.

Answer (score 2):

This will make CRGreens script a bit faster...

```
set ff to choose folder

tell application "System Events"
    set everyNef to files of ff whose name extension = "nef"
    repeat with thisNef in my everyNef
        set thisJpg to my getBaseName(thisNef) & ".jpg"
        if not (exists file thisJpg of ff) then delete thisNef
    end repeat
end tell

-- This handler is not limited to .jpg
on getBaseName(aFile)
    tell application "System Events" to set {fileName, fileExt} to {name, name extension} of aFile
    return text 1 thru ((get offset of "." & fileExt in fileName) - 1) of fileName
end getBaseName
```

Comment: This having two upvotes is misleading. I'm partially to blame, as I upvoted w|o testing first. On my system this is the slowest of all the variants.

Answer (score 1):

[edited to include faster version using do shell script]
faster version:

```
set macStyleFF to choose folder
set ff to (POSIX path of macStyleFF)
tell application "Finder"
    --first get all the .nef files (names)
    set everyNef to do shell script "cd '" & ff & "';ls *.nef" --name of every file of ff whose name ends with ".nef"
    set everyNef to (every paragraph of everyNef)

    repeat with thisNef in everyNef
        --use this list to see if there is a jpg of same name
        if file ((text 1 thru -5 of thisNef) & ".jpg") of macStyleFF exists then
            --it has a companion
        else
            --if not, send it to the trash
            delete (file thisNef of macStyleFF)
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Not as fast version using Finder 'whose clause':

```
set ff to choose folder
tell application "Finder"
    --first get all the .nef files (names)
    set everyNef to name of every file of ff whose name ends with ".nef"
    repeat with thisNef in everyNef
        --use this list to see if there is a jpg of same name
        if file ((text 1 thru -5 of thisNef) & ".jpg") of ff exists then
            --it has a companion
        else
            --if not, send it to the trash
            delete (file thisNef of ff)
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Note that this will leave any orphan jpgs in there, but won't leave orphan .nef files

Comment: Not surprisingly, the terminal one-liner is the best. I was too lazy to put it together! Thanks to Lauri Ranta.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that it's slow using a whose claus on a large folder and it's slow searching a large folder many times in a repeat loop looking for jpg files. So I suggest you do neither.

We can get the names of the files once, and then use that list of names to do our searching. Plus we can put that list into a script object which makes the script much faster when you're dealing with large lists.

This script ran in 2 seconds on a folder with 1500 files. There were 1000 nefs in the folder and 500 of them didn't have a jpg file.

```
set ff to choose folder
set ffText to ff as text

script s
    property everyFileName : missing value
end script

set inTime to current date
tell application "System Events"
    set s's everyFileName to name of files of ff
end tell

repeat with aName in s's everyFileName
    if (text -3 thru -1 of aName) is "nef" then
        if (text 1 thru -4 of aName & "jpg") is not in s's everyFileName then
            tell application "System Events" to delete file (ffText & aName)
        end if
    end if
end repeat
set s's everyFileName to missing value

set totalTime to (current date) - inTime
return totalTime
```

Comment: Hi Regulus. Notice that I used a (top level) script object in my script as well... "repeat with thisNef in MY everyNef"

Comment: I like this approach ... +1

Comment: I did notice that adayzdone. I've never used it that way... I always do it the way I showed here... but I have seen discussions about its speed and use. I just need to tinker with it so I can understand it better before I start using it.

Answer (score 0):

I tested 3 versions, each with a folder of about 1700 files.
The System Events version: 61s.

My faster version using do shell in first part: 31s.

The method below using another do shell to delete the files: 19 (or less -- it did it in 9s and 7s). *[edit: see note and cleaned up code below]*

```
set macStyleFF to choose folder
set ff to (POSIX path of macStyleFF)
set d to current date
tell application "Finder"
    --first get all the .nef files (names)
    set everyNef to do shell script "cd '" & ff & "';ls *.nef" --name of every file of ff whose name ends with ".nef"
    set everyNef to (every paragraph of everyNef)

    repeat with thisNef in everyNef
        --use this list to see if there is a jpg of same name
        if file ((text 1 thru -5 of thisNef) & ".jpg") of macStyleFF exists then
            --it has a companion
        else
            --if not, send it to the trash
            --delete (file thisNef of macStyleFF)
            do shell script "rm '" & ff & thisNef & "'"
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

**[cleaning up the code to make it more efficient (as per adayzone's suggestion) yields the script below, which clocks in at 5-6 seconds.]**

```
set macStyleFF to choose folder
set ff to (POSIX path of macStyleFF)

set everyNef to do shell script "cd '" & ff & "';ls *.nef" --name of every file of ff whose name ends with ".nef"
set everyNef to (every paragraph of everyNef)

repeat with thisNef in everyNef
    tell application "Finder" to file ((text 1 thru -5 of thisNef) & ".jpg") of macStyleFF exists
--or ((do shell script "[ -f " & ff & ((text 1 thru -5 of thisNef) & ".jpg") & " ] && echo \"true\" || echo \"false\"") as boolean)
    --use this list to see if there is a jpg of same name
    if (result) then
        --it has a companion
    else
        --if not, send it to the trash
        --delete (file thisNef of macStyleFF)
        do shell script "rm '" & ff & thisNef & "'"
    end if
end repeat
```

Comment: And I just did another test with my original whose clause, Finder version at 45s. Go figure.

Comment: My original answer, using Finder whose clause: (45s). adayzone's SE version: 1 min. (sorry, that's what I got). w/initial do shell: 31s. w/do shell to collect initial list of .nef's and do shell to do delete (rm): 7-19s. regulus6633's SE version: 12s. Lauri's bash one-liner: 2s. Re: AppleScript, I admit to having bias about using System Events if it isn't needed, but if it is faster at some things, good to know. Note: these tests not perfect -- some randomness to how many orphans get created in my original folder creation process. Most tests ultimately were done with duplicated folder, tho.

Comment: Good comparisons, thanks for the updates. I wonder why such a large difference in my script. You measure 12 seconds versus my 2 seconds. I have a SSD. Do you? That would account for the difference.

Comment: Yeah, that would do it!

Comment: Hi CR. You should avoid including "do shell script" within a tell Finder Block. Also instead of cd '" & ff & "' , the proper form is cd " & quoted form of ff * " .

Comment: Ok, one last trick. putting the following line might also speed it up (sometimes results are not consistent -- I get 3-5 secs for execution on my system). I also really like this shell script trick to check for existence of file which replaces the Finder 'exists' line:  ((do shell script "[ -f " & ff & ((text 1 thru -5 of thisNef) & ".jpg") & " ] && echo \"true\" || echo \"false\"") as boolean)